# How to export a 50 row tableGrob-table

Tags: r, gridextra

I've got a `50` row table made with `tableGrob().`

The table itself's fit for purpose, with the two first columns aligned to the left and the remaining three columns centered.

The problem's that I can't export it (I'd prefer something like `PNG`, `JPEG`). When I try I only get a small section of it!!

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
library(gridExtra) 
library(grid)

myiris1 <- iris[1:50,1:2] # df with columns to be aligned to the left 
myiris2 <- iris[1:50,3:5] # df with columns to be centered  

tt3 <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.1)),    # theme for alignment to the left 
                      colhead=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.1))) 

g1 <- tableGrob(myiris1,rows = NULL,theme=tt3) # table with columns aligned to the left
g2 <- tableGrob(myiris2,rows = NULL) # table with columns centered (by default) 

haligned <- gtable_combine(g1,g2, along=1) # align the two tables horizontally to make a single table  
grid.arrange(haligned, ncol=1)
```

Comment: Maybe table is too long, try to set height of jpeg, e.g.: `jpeg("temp.jpeg", width = 1000, height = 5000); grid.arrange(haligned, ncol=1); dev.off()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tableHTML` to create such a table:

```
iris[1:50, ] %>% 
# create tableHTML without rownames
tableHTML(rownames = FALSE) %>% 
# add lightgray background to every 2nd row
  add_css_row(css = list(c('background-color'), c('lightgray')), 
              rows = even(1:50)) %>% 
# align the text of columns 3:5
  add_css_column(columns = 3:5,
                 css = list(c('text-align'),
                            c('center'))) %>% 
# use html tools to print to the viewer
  htmltools::html_print()
```

Then simply click on Export to create a PNG

[image: export_button]

Another way would be to use `webshot` to convert an HTML file to PNG:

```
iris[1:50, ] %>% 
 tableHTML(rownames = FALSE) %>% 
  add_css_row(css = list(c('background-color'), c('lightgray')), 
              rows = even(1:50)) %>% 
  add_css_column(columns = 3:5,
                 css = list(c('text-align'),
                            c('center'))) %>% 
  write_tableHTML(file = "table.html", complete_html = TRUE)

webshot::webshot("table.html")
```

You will then find a file called `webshot.png` in your working directory.